# Connection refused for Sanity API call

Tags: php, sanity

I'm using the [sanity php client](https://github.com/sanity-io/sanity-php) to fetch some data off of sanity.

This is my query:

```
$results = $client->fetch(
    '*[_type == "article" && slug.current == $slug ]{name, intro}[0]',
    ['slug' => $slug]
);
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: 
Connection refused for URI https://someProject.api.sanity.io/v2021-03-25/data/query/public?query=someQuery 
in /www/htdocs/w01bd9f6/dev/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/StreamHandler.php:321
```

The odd thing is: everything works fine in my local dev environment. but testing this on the webserver results in the error.
I added the CORS origins so both localhost and the Webserver are allowed to connect to sanity. php versions are the same.

Comment: Perhaps the webserver doesn't allow outgoing http connections (or only allows them to a set of whitelisted destinations). Check the firewall, or contact the system adminstrator. N.B. CORS is irrelevant here because you're making the request from PHP, not via AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up a .htaccess so the webserver php parses html files. Apparently Guzzle didn't like that.
When I changed my files to .php everything worked as expected.